# NoSuchElementException in Selenium Webdriver in python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, nosuchelementexception

```html
div class="row-fluid">
<div id="sfx" class="span12">
<ui-view>
<div class="row-fluid fa-rep-nav">
<div id="test"></div>
<div class="row-fluid">
<div id="sfx" class="span12">
<ui-view>
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span12">
<div class="ledger-btn-block clearfix">
<form class="ng-pristine ng-valid" name="reportGenForm">
<span class="input-append ledger-date-block fa-block-pull-left">
<label class="ledger-label">Select‌·Report:‌·&nbsp;</label>
<select class="select_report_type ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="selectedReport" ng-options="str.name for str in reportType">
<label class="ledger-label">&nbsp;‌·Date‌·Range:‌·&nbsp;</label>
<input class="date-picker report-date-input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" date-range-picker="" readonly="" ng-model="sfxReportModel.date" options="selectedReport.opts" min="selectedReport.opts.minDate" max="selectedReport.opts.maxDate" type="text">
<i class="icon-calendar add-on no-border-radius"></i>
</span>
```

I have used all the method of locating an element which are applicable here. I have also used time.sleep() function so that the page on which I am locating element can load successfully before finding, but even then also location is not appearing.Here is the pic of html code. Highlighted is the one I want to locate.
I have used methods like find_element_by_xpath and find_by_class_name where i get xpath using Firebug but getting the same error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z55TX.png). I need help in locating "select" tag.

Comment: Instead of *describing* what you have tried post the actual code you. Also, post html as text, not as image.

Comment: Now html version of code is added.

Comment: Can you add some code what you have tried and what you want to locate. the explanation you given is not clear

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you want to select the dropdown. Use the following code in python to select a dropdown value

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@class='select_report_type ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid']"))
select.select_by_index(1)
// OR
select.select_by_visible_text("text")
// OR
select.select_by_value(value)
```

Let me know if still facing same issue or any further things